# the Qgridlayout does not appear properly when using for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, pyqt5

I am surfing from a problem in using for loops when I have done instead of doing all of the design by hand what I did instead is using for-loops to loop through each button the code just goes well but I am going to paste it all to see if there was problem in another
place and to make it easier for you to import and run it on your machine

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton , QWidget , QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
class windowExamlpe(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        gridlayout =QGridLayout()
        btn1 = QPushButton("click 1" , self)
        btn2 = QPushButton("click 2" ,self)
        btn3 = QPushButton("click 3" , self)
        btn4 = QPushButton("click 4" , self)
        btn5 = QPushButton("click 5" , self)
        btn6 = QPushButton("click 6" ,self)
        btn7 = QPushButton("click 7" , self)
        btn8 = QPushButton("click 8" , self)
        btns = [btn1 , btn2 , btn3 , btn4 , btn5 , btn5, btn6 , btn7 ,btn8]#list
        x = 0
        y = 0
        #here starts the problem I have written the rest so that it will be easier for you-
        #-to answer
        for btn in btns:#loop through each button
            while y < 4:#if y is still smaller than the number of buttons
                
                y+=1#add 1 if the above while loop happened
                gridlayout.addWidget(btn , x , y)#add the buttons and thier positions
                if y == 4:#but if y is equal to 4 
                    x += 1#add one to x
                    y -= 4 # and subtract 4 from y which is 4
                    
                    while y < 4: # if y is still smaller than 4                
                        y+=1 #then add 1 untill it is 4
                        gridlayout.addWidget(btn , x , y)#and               
        self.setLayout(gridlayout)
                   
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = windowExamlpe() 
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Do you want to place a certain amount of buttons in a grid layout, with a specific number of columns?

Comment: @musicamante yes y = 4 x = 2

Comment: @musicamante is there anything else is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is unnecessarily complex, and conceptually wrong.

The main issue is that you'll end up only adding the first button, and after that the cycle will exit since `y` is already 4.

If you want to place buttons in a grid with a fixed amount of columns, then just add 1 to `x` for every cycle, and if then it's bigger than the column amount, reset it to 0 and add 1 to `y`.

Also note that your list has a duplicate, and remember that [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1) arguments are `row, column`, not the opposite.

```
        x = 0
        y = 0
        columns = 4
        btns = [btn1 , btn2 , btn3 , btn4 , btn5 , btn6 , btn7 ,btn8]
        for btn in btns:
            gridlayout.addWidget(btn, y, x)
            x += 1
            if x == columns:
                x = 0
                y += 1
```